# Enable multi-line paste for conda python shell on 18.04

Tags: command-line, 18.04, python, anaconda

I am running ubuntu 18.04 and have started using conda 4.9.2 to set up python environments. As this is a remote machine, I often copy and paste short multi-line code snippets for development purposes.

In the default python shell this works without problems:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
```

In the conda environment the code seems to be pasted in bracketed mode raising an error:

```
$ python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import pandas as pd

    ^
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
>>>
```

Is there any way to enable the default pasting behaviour in the conda environment as well? The bracketed paste mode only seems to be active within the conda python shell, i.e. `bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste off'` does not change the behaviour. This seems to be an issue specific to 18.04. On another machine running 20.04 this problem does not appear.

Comment: FYI: Are you really running 18.04.3? or that was what you initially installed? as 18.04.3 implies your a year+ behind on upgraded packages as a fully-updated 18.04 system will report itself as 18.04.5  (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/02/12/ubuntu-18-04-4-lts-released/)

Comment: Yes, it is 18.04.3. This is an openstack based installation and I avoid updating anything beyond security updates.

Comment: Updated to 18.04.5 which does not fix it. I tested it under 20.04 on another machine where the issue does not appear.

Comment: I've had this issue with Python 3.7.11 on both Ubuntu 20.04 and CentOS 7. The system Python worked but Conda version was broken. The problem disappeared after upgrading to Python 3.8 or later.